# Click to open children html in fancyBox and link them

Tags: jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

I have this project where I can't combine images into one composite, so I have to have 2 images per one overlay. So far, this fiddle below does the trick, but I can't for the life of me figure out how to get the back and next buttons to relate them to each other.

http://jsfiddle.net/PFVxK/1344/

HTML

```
<div class="image">
    <div rel="gallery1">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/300x300/B7AF90/FFFFFF&text=Before" />
        <img src="http://placehold.it/300x300/B7AF90/FFFFFF&text=After" />
        <p class="title">Title Goes Here</p>
    </div>
    <br style="clear:both;" />
</div>
<div class="image">
    <div rel="gallery1">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/300x300/B7AF90/FFFFFF&text=Before2" />
        <img src="http://placehold.it/300x300/B7AF90/FFFFFF&text=After2" />
        <p class="title">Title Goes Here</p>
    </div>
    <br style="clear:both;" />
</div>
```

JQuery

```
$(".image").click(function () {

    $.fancybox({
        type: 'html',
        content: $(this).children().html()
    }).attr('rel', 'gallery1');

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you are triggering fancybox using a manual method (`click`) so you can't have a gallery this way unless you set the gallery elements within the script itself.

Try this variation instead :

```
var images = [];
$(".image").each(function(i){
    images[i] = $(this).children().html();
    $(this).on("click", function(){
        $.fancybox(images,{
            index: i,
            type: 'html'
        });
    })
});
```

**Notice** that `.on()` requires jQuery v1.7+

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/95msy/)**

Comment: Thank you so, so, so much. I'm using 2.0.3 of jQuery for modern and ie8 gets 1.8.3 so this is working great!!!